# How do I stretch a background image to fill the window and get it to animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a project I'm working on I need to stretch a background image to fill the browser window *and* be able to have them transition via sliding eg. Say you're on the home page, I'd want the user to be able to click on a navigation link for 'About', and then have the background image slide into a different image.

Usually I'd use [backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) to stretch an image to fill the browser window, but I need to be able to slide to a new image.

I can use backstretch to fill the window, and I can get the sliding working *IF* I'm using divs of fixed dimensions.. but is it possible to combine the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on browser support, you could use multiple background images.

And you can always animate background-position.